# Will my explorers return safely?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Pls give me hope. I think I have left them exploring for too long. :(
[image: Explorer #1]

[image: Explorer #2]

Update : looks like they will return safely.... Screenshot after 12 hours [image: updated status]

Comment: I don't remember if they even take damage coming back, actually. Either way, they're well supplied, and 12 hours coming back isn't that bad

Comment: Hope it's so... Wat abt the other guy? 20+ hours left...

Comment: He's got 6 stimpacks. He'll probably be fine. Either way, nothing you can really do now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While an explorer is returning, nothing can happen to them.

There will be no events, no loot, no damage taken, no xp gain and no healing.

Comment: You are right.. Looks like they will return safely

Comment: In addition to this, were the explorer to die out in the wastes, you can revive them for a certain amount of caps (I believe 20xlevel) and they will return safely with their complete inventory and loot.